# C special math functions with bsd/mit - like license

Tags: c, math

are you aware of a trusted (i.e. efficient and accurate) implementation of special math functions (like gamma, beta, error and inverse error functions) for the C language available with a non-gpl license? BSD or MIT licenses are fine.

So something like:
http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Special-Functions.html

but with a more permissive license. I am aware boost have something similar but it's a bit overkill to add dependency on boost just for this...
Moreover C would be preferable in this context...

Thanks!

Comment: More permissive than GPL? In which sense?

Comment: To clarify I am not looking to start a discussion on open source licenses :) So I apologize for the inaccurate wording. My issue is that I want to license my library with a BSD-like license so I cannot link to GPL projects.

Comment: No no, that's ok, I understand completely. Just thought it was  strange initially :-P

Comment: All of the standard libm implementations I'm aware of have very permissive licenses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to the questions below contain links to some excellent libraries, including  *fdlibm* and *cephes*:

- [C library of single-precision transcendental functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111847/c-library-of-single-precision-transcendental-functions)
- [long double math library implementations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945129/long-double-math-library-implementations)
- [Platform independent math library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129032/platform-independent-math-library)

Comment: I don't see evidence of special functions in those links.

Comment: @David, Cephes has all those mentioned, except the inverse error function. See for instance http://www.netlib.org/cephes/doubldoc.html. fdlibm has gamma and erf. See http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/

Comment: Can the Cephes library be included in a BSD project?

Comment: http://www.netlib.no/netlib/research/boilerplate has the default terms for netlib; it dates from the university research free sharing days before fussy licensing like GPL.

Comment: The license of cephes is not clear. The readme states *"Some software in this archive may be from the book _Methods and
Programs for Mathematical Functions_ (Prentice-Hall, 1989) or
from the Cephes Mathematical Library, a commercial product. In
either event, it is copyrighted by the author.  What you see here
may be used freely but it comes with no support or guarantee."*. But see also https://lists.debian.org/debian-legal/2004/12/msg00295.html

Answer (score 0):

ATLAS has C bindings. http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/
ATLAS has a BSD style license. http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/faq.html#license

Comment: Yes, but atlas is for vector/matrix computations, while I am looking specifically for gamma, beta, error and inverse error (plus eventually log of them), bessel ecc. ecc. functions (from double to to double).

Comment: atlas is a blas which, whilst useful, is not the subject of this question

Answer (score 0):

C99 stdlib has the functions you mentioned, there's no need to go with an external library:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math

Just look for a cstdlib implementation that suits your licensing needs.
glibc is released under LGPL btw (not the same as GPL)!